# Is it possible to point your domain to a website and still keep emails on the old domain provider?

Tags: domain-name-system

I have been struggling with an issue for a long time.

I have bought a domain from mauritiusbiz.

I made a website on wix.com

When I wanted to connect my website to my domain, the Wix support **pointed** the website to the domain.

Since then, I cant receive any email. Emails appear on Sent Items Box but receivers do not receive them.

Wix asked me to create an "A" record and a "CName" record. I added that to the DNS settings on the domain provider domain settings.

I still cannot receive emails.

Where am I going wrong?

I just need that the website address be the domain I bought and keep my emails hosted on the current provider. Is that possible?

Comment: Without knowing exactly what your configuration is, all anyone can do is guess at what the problem might be.

Answer (score 1):

It is very possible to have mails going one place and web traffic to another for the same domain.

For mail delivery an MX record (or multiple MX records) are added to the dns zone. The MX record points to a domain name - that domain name in tern needs to resolve to an IP address - but does not need to relate to the parent domain. Thus if your domain is example.com you could set the MX record to (among others) ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM if your mail provider was gmail.

I wonder of the default settings for your MX need to be updated, and/or if the SMTP and pip/IMAP settings in your email software need to be updated to not reflect your base domain name.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but please configure the MX record to point to your domain where your email are.

As you stated it I guess you don't have any MX configured currently.

Comment: Hi,we were using the emails before the 'pointing' was made. the mx records were not changed at all.The only record that wix asked is to creat the 'A' record and the 'CNAME' record. The 'MX' that is on my domain provider settings is showing to sataree-com.mail.protection.outlook.com. Is there anything i am missing/ Wix support says they only pointed the website to the domain. Any reason as to why my emails are having issues? Can you help? I want to keep my current domain provider and my website on wix? is that possible?

Comment: @Kamal the issue seem somewhere else then. The email are sent or not, please try sending test email from/to gmail and check the result please

Comment: @kamal Absent MX records, SMTP will attempt to deliver email to the A record of the domain. This is an as-per-design fallback behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Go to mauritiusbiz domain/dns manager they should have at-least a simple DNS manager:

- First set the DNS server to point to wix.com DNS servers(you should
  of received all this info from them IP's, DNS servers..etc from
  wix).
- Then you should head to wix.com DNS manager and do your settings
  there.

Pointing your domain name to Wix Servers will let you do all your domain DNS operation from Wix DNS manager.